# Conditional view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the table from which I need to create conditionalize view.

[image]

and I am getting one flag from different table. So based on the flag values i.e. if flag=1 then I need to display actual column values from table, and if flag=0 then show all column values as null values.
I know we can handle it using CASE statement but here, in may case column count is very big so need to handle it in better way.

Comment: May be you can use [transparent data encryption](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ASOAG/introduction-to-transparent-data-encryption.htm#ASOAG10117) for this?

Comment: Where does that flag come from? You can't pass parameters to a view

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `CASE` expression along with `REGEXP_REPLACE` to mask the value column:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN Value ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(Value, '.', '*') END AS Value
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks... as per above solution, I need to add CASE for each column in the table which very lengthy task, as I have 100+ columns in the table.  So can we handle it on complete table level ?

Comment: @New_User In that case, you might want to look into handling the masking in your view layer (e.g. something like PHP, Java, Python, etc.).  Otherwise, you basically would need a separate `CASE` expression for every column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as flag from dual) x left join
     t
     on x.flag = :flag;
```

If `:flag = 1`, then all columns will be shown.  If `:flag` is anything else, then all values will be `NULL`.

If you actually want to show the ids, it is a little more complicated:

```
select i.*, t.*
from (select 1 as flag from dual) x left join
     (select id, . . .  -- columns you want to keep
      from t
     ) i left join
     t
     on x.flag = :flag and t.id = i.id;
```

You will probably need to list out the columns with the `NULL` values.